# Is there a leveling penaltiy in Skyrim like there was in Oblivion?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

In Oblivion if I leveled Destruction and nothing else I would soon fall behind because I would only get the +5 bonus in one skill.

I am new to Skyrim, but I don't want to make a similar mistake.  Is there attribute level issues to leveling a single skill?

Note: I read this question: [Are there any disadvantages to leveling too fast in skyrim?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/36050/are-there-any-disadvantages-to-leveling-too-fast-in-skyrim) but it is not really what I am asking.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No matter which skills you level, you get the same attribute choice: 10 magicka, 10 health or 10 stamina + 5 carry capacity.

If you only level (for example) Alchemy, you'll get some levels and the attribute and perk points that come with them.  Without other skills, you might be very restricted in how you may spend those perks - or you can save them until you get enough skill to buy the perk you want.  Without any combat skills, the world in general might be a scary place - however there are still low level bandits for you to kick around to get combat skills.

Answer (score 4):

No, there is nothing to worry about when it comes to what skills contribute to your level. Skyrim was designed with all the criticism of Oblivion taken into account, and is much more fluid and forgiving.

Comment: Unless you *only* level non-combat skills, at which point you're in trouble. (But then if you're doing that, what are you doing wandering in the dangerous wilderness away from your shop? ;)